# FlatList rendering is heavy for big data set

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-flatlist

In my application I have a `FlatList` with dataset of 100 items in it. Each item has a complex UI and I noticed that it's taking a heavy toll on performance. The page that has the list takes up to 5 seconds to load.
I noticed that the moment the component is rendered for the first time, the `renderItem` function of the `FlatList` is also called for each and every item in my data set, I also noticed that it also happens if there any other setState change for other stuff on that page. Is there a way to prevent this re-rendering of the flat list or at least to re-render only the visible items - just like with Recycle with in native Android?
How can I only render the visible items when the component first appears?
I tried to use `initialNumToRender` and `maxToRenderPerBatch` but neither have worked.

Here is an example of the code:

```
const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

const App = () => {

  const [text, setText] = React.useState('')

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    console.log("Render Item")
    return (<Item title={item.title} />)
};

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>

      <TextInput
        value={text}
        onChangeText={(val) => setText(val)}
      />

      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        initialNumToRender={6}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={6}
      />

    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

If I try to type something in `TextInput` the whole list re-renders but nothing in the list has changed.. how can I prevent this?

Comment: "but nothing in the list has changed", if `FlatList` is a class component, making use of `React.memo` or has either `renderItem` or `keyExtractor` as part of a dependency array of a hook then it very much is changing. When the `text` state updates `App` will rerender and create a new `renderItem` function and a new anonymous function for `keyExtractor` both of these will FAIL a reference comparison causing the list to rerender.